# What does idl attribute mean in the WHATWG html5 standard document?

Tags: html, standards, idl

While reading over the WHATWG's [HTML5 - A technical specification for Web developers](http://developers.whatwg.org) I see many references such as:

> ## Reflecting content attributes in IDL attributes
>
> Some IDL attributes are defined to reflect a particular content
>   attribute. This means that on getting, the IDL attribute returns the
>   current value of the content attribute, and on setting, the IDL
>   attribute changes the value of the content attribute to the given
>   value.

and:

> In conforming documents, there is only one body element. The
>   document.body IDL attribute provides scripts with easy access to a
>   document's body element.
>
> The body element exposes as event handler content attributes a number
>   of the event handlers of the Window object. It also mirrors their
>   event handler IDL attributes.

My (admittedly fuzzy) understanding comes from the Windows world. I think an .idl file is used to map remote procedure calls in an n-tier distributed app. I would assume a content attribute refers to html element attributes.

There is no place in the standard *that I can see* that explains this usage of the terms "content attribute" and "IDL attribute". Could anyone explain what these terms mean and how the two kinds of attributes relate?

Comment: An example of an IDL attribute is `innerHTML` of an `Element`. When you set a value to this attribute, it triggers a change of the DOM after parsing the supplied value. It is very much unlike a content attribute.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The IDL ([Interface Definition Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_description_language)) comes from the [Web IDL](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/WebIDL/) spec:

> This document defines an interface definition language, Web IDL, that
>   can be used to describe interfaces that are intended to be implemented
>   in web browsers. Web IDL is an IDL variant with a number of features
>   that allow the behavior of common script objects in the web platform
>   to be specified more readily. How interfaces described with Web IDL
>   correspond to constructs within ECMAScript execution environments is
>   also detailed in this document.

Content attributes are the ones that appear in the markup:

```
<div id="mydiv" class="example"></div>
```

In the above code `id` and `class` are attributes.  Usually a content attribute will have a corresponding IDL attribute.

For example, the following JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('mydiv').className = 'example'
```

Is equivalent to setting the `class` content attribute.

In JavaScript texts, the IDL attributes are often referred to as properties because they are exposed as properties of DOM objects to JavaScript.

While there's usually a corresponding pair of a content attribute and an IDL attribute/property, they are not necessarily interchangeable. For example, for an `<option>` element:

- the content attribute `selected` indicates the *initial* state of the option (and does not change when the user changes the option),
- the property `selected` reflects the *current* state of the control

Comment: Thank you for the link to Web IDL. And this is supposed to be the "readable" version!

Comment: So what about e.g. onclick and others? I read somewhere on Mozillas mailingslists that these are IDL attributes but they also appear in the markup... They described content attributes as the ones which affect the rendering process.

Comment: The `selected` content attribute value is both readable and writable as the `defaultSelected` IDL attribute/property of the `<option>`.

Comment: And what about non-standard, custom attributes. For example `<div roka="42">` and in javascript `myDiv.roka` different values. Why? What is the standard in this case?