# img element in HTML: file attribute and src attribute behaves differently

Tags: html, fileapi

I have a `file` attribute that is saved on a certain `<img id = "one">` element. Said `file` attribute contains an object of [`File` type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File). I have antother `<img id = "two">` element. When I try this:

`document.getElementById('two').src = document.getElementById('one').file`

it behaves differently with:

`document.getElementById('two').file = document.getElementById('one').file`

The first line of code returns the `string` representation of my `File` contained in `img one` and the second line of code returns the **actual `File` object**. What's with this difference of behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HTMLImageElement`s [don't have a `file` attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-img-element:concept-element-dom), so when you assign `document.getElementById('two').file`, you're just creating a `file` property on the JavaScript object representing `<img id="two">`. Access that property, and you get back the `File` you put in.

But `document.getElementById('two').src` is an [IDL attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12355195/9029328) that reflects the `src` content attribute of the `img` element. The `src` content attribute contains the address of the image, so when you access the `src` IDL attribute from JavaScript, you get the file converted to a string:

> [**2.7.1 Reflecting content attributes in IDL attributes**](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-dom-interfaces.html#reflecting-content-attributes-in-idl-attributes)
>
> Some IDL attributes are defined to reflect a particular content attribute. This means that on getting, the IDL attribute returns the current value of the content attribute, and on setting, the IDL attribute changes the value of the content attribute to the given value.
>
> [...]
>
> If a reflecting IDL attribute is a USVString attribute whose content attribute is defined to contain a URL, then on getting, if the content attribute is absent, the IDL attribute must return the empty string. Otherwise, the IDL attribute must parse the value of the content attribute relative to the element's node document and if that is successful, return the resulting URL string. If parsing fails, then the value of the content attribute must be returned instead, converted to a USVString.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with files, use `<input type="file">`, otherwise you can't put a "file" into a `<img>` tag